# Python pandas - add the missing column and make two dataframe columns in same order

Tags: python, pandas

Two dataframes train and test. The train dataframe has columns A, Z, D, C and test has columns C, D, Z. How do I take train's columns and make test dataframe also has four columns with the same order as train? The newly added columns A should have value 0 for all rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using `reindex`

```
test['A']=0
test.reindex_axis(train.columns, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assign` to create a new column `A` on `test` and use list of column names to reorder the columns:

```
test.assign(A = 0)[['A', 'Z', 'D', 'C']]
```

Or: `test.assign(A = 0)[train.columns]`

---

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': [1,2,3],
    'D': [2,3,4],
    'Z': [3,4,5]
})

test.assign(A = 0)[['A','Z','D','C']]

#   A   Z   D   C
#0  0   3   2   1
#1  0   4   3   2
#2  0   5   4   3
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use `pd.concat` as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_train = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": np.random.randn(10),
    "Z": np.random.randn(10),
    "D": np.random.randn(10),
    "C": np.random.randn(10)
})

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "Z": np.random.randn(10),
    "D": np.random.randn(10),
    "C": np.random.randn(10)
})

df_all = pd.concat([df_train, df_test], axis=0)
df_all = df_all.fillna(0)

df_train = df_all.iloc[0:len(df_train.index)]
df_test = df_all.iloc[len(df_train.index)+1:len(df_all.index)]
```

Comment: Or may be change to `pd.concat([train,test],axis=0,keys=['train','test']).loc['test'].fillna(0)`, still a nice new way for this type of question :~)

Comment: Thanks for the supplement. I was helpful too.